# c++ code will not return my trigonometry table (beginner)

Tags: c++

I am currently in an introduction to programming class, and still don't know much. My current assignment is to write a program that returns a table that gives the cosine, sine, and tangent for every 15 angles from 0 to 90. I don't believe my code has any bugs, but the code won't run. I'm not sure if my computer is just too trash or what. Here's the code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double ang_deg = 0;

    double ang_rad = 0;

    while (ang_deg < 91);
    {
        ang_rad = (ang_deg * M_PI) / 180.0;

        cout << setw(7) << "ANGLE" << setw(7) << "SIN" << setw(7) << "COS" << setw(7) << "TAN" << endl;

        cout << fixed << setprecision(3);

        cout << setw(7) << ang_deg << setw(7) << sin(ang_rad) << setw(7) << cos(ang_rad) << setw(7) << tan(ang_rad) << endl;

        ang_deg += 15;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have had a diagnostics running for about 10 minutes. My other programs have took about 30 seconds.

[My IDE and console which should have my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5itTS.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you expect `while (ang_deg < 91);` to mean? In particular, what is the purpose of the `;`? "I'm not sure if my computer is just too trash or what." Running this code (with the typo fixed) is much easier than compiling it. "I have had a diagnostics running for about 10 minutes." Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to study some basic techniques for debugging code. If something is taking too long and producing no output, you should first suspect an infinite loop.

Comment: "I don't believe my code has any bugs" One thing I've learned over 30 years of programming is that you should always assume your code has bugs. Often it doesn't, but assuming the worst helps you examine the code with a critical eye to prove it to yourself. A debugger helps a lot too because as soon as you stepped through that line and saw the program didn't advance you'd know something was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bug

```
while (ang_deg < 91);
```

should be

```
while (ang_deg < 91)
```

Your version is an *empty* while loop, because the loop is empty `ang_deg` never changes and so the loop never terminates. That's why your program seemed not to run (in fact it did run, but it never finished).

Sometimes the smallest things can be errors.

Comment: In fact an infinite loop without side effects is Undefined Behavior. We do not know, what happened at the OP. (E.g. if the program ran at all. It could have been busy formatting the hard drive.)